# Disabling and Enabling scroll with Arrow Keys

Tags: jquery, scroll, key, isenabled

I want to disable scrolling on this website until the join mailing list button is clicked. Here is the website:
 
http://www.fashionweekny.net/

Additionally, people with PCs are telling me that no method of scrolling works at all. I dont have a PC anymore and I'm not sure why. I cant seem to find any explanation to this in S.O.s previous questions. The scrolling works the way it should on my computer(mac) with Mouse wheel, and trackpad scrolling but it seems as though the arrow keys don't scroll at all. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the type of browser.

here is the code relevant to scroll... 
JS:

```
$('#about-section').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('disable_scroll'))
    return false; 
  else
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});


if (disable_scroll == true)
  $('#about-section').addClass('disabled')
else
  $('#about-section').removeClass('disabled')


$(document).ready(function() {
  disable_scroll();
})

document.getElementById("enable").onclick = function() {
  enable_scroll();
};

document.getElementById("to-about-section").onclick = function() {
  disable_scroll();
};


var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function keydown(e) {
    for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
        if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function wheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, keydown, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, keydown, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = true;  
}
```